# Qt Creator: arm-linux-androideabi-g++: not found

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

So I am having this very annoying problem with Qt Creator. When I try to build any application I get the following:

> .../NDK/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: not found
>       Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler

Now I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178293/android-ndk-arm-linux-androideabi-g-not-found) that this might be because of due to Android Studio and this can be solved just downloading the NDK separately from Google's website. So far I have tried the following things:

- Removed Android Studio
- Installed the SDK tools separately
- Installed the NDK separately
- Downgraded my JDK version to 8
- Tried with different versions of the NDK (I have tried 20,19 and 18)

However none of these solutions work. I am using Qt Creator 4.9.2 with Qt 5.13.

Comment: did you check that path? if it's not there, is it elsewhere?

Comment: No it's not there. I wonder why Qt Creator is looking for g++ and not clang.

Comment: Well if it's looking for g++ instead of gcc it would probably need clang++, not clang. But have you performed a full system search for the file name it's looking for? It's probably just looking in the wrong place. You can change that in settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ndk r19, the toolchains are already completely changed to **llvm/clang**, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800967/8034839 for more details.

From your error message, it looks you set the toolchain to gcc rather than clang, which might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting the correct path to the toolchain I want to use

i.e. After Downloading and extracting the correct toolchain (r15c in my case) set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to that specific path of the (r15c) toolchain root folder without the ending "/".

Projects>Build & Run>Android for ...(Specific Platform)>Build>Build Environment>ANDROID_NDK_ROOT.

And it worked like a charm.